# Losing precision in Lua

Tags: lua, precision

I have a function in lua, which is given 2 vectors, return the lambda multiplier of first vector to second one, here is my code

```
function Math.vectorLambda( v1,v2 )
    local v1Length,v2Length=math.sqrt(v1.x^2+v1.y^2),math.sqrt(v2.x^2+v2.y^2)
    if v1Length==0 then
        return nil
    else
        local dotProduct=v1.x*v2.x+v1.y*v2.y
        print(dotProduct,v1Length,v2Length,math.abs(dotProduct)==(v1Length*v2Length))
        if math.abs(dotProduct)==(v1Length*v2Length) then
            if v1.x~=0 then
                return v2.x/v1.x
            else
                return v2.y/v1.y
            end
        else
            return nil
        end
    end
end
```

However, if

```
--this is what I get from terminal and I believe that it does not display the whole number--
    v1={0.51449575542753,-0.85749292571254}
    v2={-10,16.666666666667}
```

the output is

```
-19.436506316151    1   19.436506316151 false
```

which is saying the absolute value of dotProduct and v1Length*v2Length are not the same...
What is the reason for above, rather than I am blind? :(

BTW, the function is not stable..with exactly the same vectors, the function might has the same output except math.abs(dotProduct)==(v1Length*v2Length) gives true and hence return correct answer rather than nil, why?

Comment: As i said, sometimes you get true, but if you run it a few more times, there is a possiblity that you get false...and a function that can not garentee its output is useless...how can I do with it...

Comment: This cannot work. You will always have the possibility of precision errors when doing calculations with floats. The only thing you can do is requiring the output to be within a certain range that is about `+/-ops*float_precision`

Answer (score 1):

Floats are tricky. You most likely have differences on the smaller decimal places (I don't know for sure, since I get `true` here). Try printing the numbers with a bigger precision, using a function like:

```
function prec_print(v, prec)
  local format = '%.' .. prec .. 'f'
  print(string.format(format, value))
end
```

In any case, you should almost never use `==` to compare floating point equality. For floats, it's quite easy to get `false` for simple things like `a+b-b==a`. What you should probably do is to check whether de difference of the two values is less than some threshold:

```
function almost_equal(float1, float2, threshold)
  return math.abs(float1 - float2) <= threshold
end
```

But it's actually trickier than that (if, say, float1 and float2 are too far apart). Anyway, this read is mandatory for anyone working with floats: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Cheers!